# On ios pinterest sharing, getting "invalid image url" error

Tags: ios, pinterest

Need some help with iOS pinterest sharing.

When I am trying to share images with iOS `Pin It SDK`, in one device (`iPhone 4s` with `pinterest` `version 2.6.1`) getting the error "Error, Invalid parameters. 'image url' (value http%3A%2F%2Ffarm8.staticflickr.com%2F7027%2F6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg) is not a valid URL format".

And the same is working fine in other devices with `pinterest version 3` and above.

So is there anything that we should take care with `URL encoding` in different `Pinterest versions`? Please help me to find where I am going wrong.

Comment: this is because of flickr's restrictions, it does not want the hidden image URL pinned, the URL should begin with flickr.com -  not staticflickr.com

Comment: My problem was because of older version of pinterest. Once I upgraded, its working fine. And had not added any specific encoding for lower version.